# Data Passing from Parent Fragment to Tabbed Fragment (child) - Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs

I want to pass data from Parent Fragment to Tabbed Fragment(child) for the initial data passing ( when the parent fragment is loading for the 1st time)  i used Bundle data. and when in nested fragments in child fragment i call PopbackStack() in order to go back with the button click. in there i need to update bundle data which is passed before into child tab fragment. bundling data doesn't get updated dataset

**Parent fragment - initial state**

```
 public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) getView().findViewById(R.id.pager);
        CropFragAdapter adapter = new CropFragAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());



        Fragment tabfragment1 = new CropAlreadyPlantedFragment();
        Fragment tabfragment2 = new FuturePlantedFragment();


            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("RAWJsonArr", INITAL_DATA_FOR_TAB_1);
            tabfragment1.setArguments(b);

            b.putString("RAWJsonArr", INITAL_DATA_FOR_TAB_2);
            tabfragment2.setArguments(b);



        adapter.addFragment(tabfragment1, "Already Planted");
        adapter.addFragment(tabfragment2, "Future Planted");


        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }
```

**Child Fragment - Tab Fragment**

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        cropAlreadyPlantedModel = new CropAlreadyPlantedModel();
        String RAWJsonArr =null;
        Bundle b = getArguments();
        if (b != null) {
            RAWJsonArr = b.getString("RAWJsonArr");
            JSONOBJ = null;
            try {
                DATASET = new JSONArray(RAWJsonArr);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        View view = cropAlreadyPlantedModel.getCropItems(inflater, container, getContext(), DATASET);
        return view;
    }
```

**Child->Child Fragment's Button Click**

```
 public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            saveBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button);
            saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        obj.put("crop_details",DATASETARRY);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if(SELECTED_TAB ==0) {
                        childDataCropDetails = obj; //static variable in Parent Fragment
                    }
                    else if(SELECTED_TAB ==1){
                        Future_childDataCropDetails = obj; //static variable in Parent Fragment
                    }
                    FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();


                    manager.popBackStack();

                }
            });


        }
```

What i miss here? please help

Answer (score 0):

issue was the scope which i'm talking in the Child Fragment was wrong ( not Current scope).

```
Bundle b = this.getArguments();
```